# How to test only we wanted test cases

Tags: selenium

In project we have 200 test cases, but every it total excution is difficult, so we want to run only 150 to 156 test cases how to do this in selenium. It is posible ,it possible how to do this.

Comment: This depends on your testing environment, not Selenium.

Comment: Ok,in any frame work it is possible

Comment: In any frame it is possible, please take and simple explanation on any framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controlling which tests execute is why many people use additional packages.  TestNG was mentioned but another is [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/).  With cucumber you specify which tests (or groups of tests) are executed using [tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using java for your test, you can made a class for each test. you can includes 150 tests in a package and using Maven and TestNG, generate a testing.xml files saying that the Test Suite just have to run the package with 150 tests on it

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend Testng.
You can achieve this with the help of groups
Your test will be like this:

```
@Test(groups={"P0"})
public void demotest {
    //code goes here
  }
```

Then run this mvn command

> mvn -Dgroups=P0 test

Answer (score 0):

Split your test cases into groups and then run them on a group by group basis. Here is some information TestNG's Groups http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups